# How to stop 'drop' speed increase?

Tags: javascript, canvas, constructor

The issue is that every time a new drop is added by pressing the 'Space' key, the speed of all the drops increases, the speed is determined by the movepi function in the Drop Constructor. Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks. 
The Code Snippet below can be tested by pressing the SpaceBar.

```js
// Get Random //
function rand(min, max) {
    "use strict";
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);
}

// Setup Canvas //
var canvas = document.querySelector("#make"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Create Drop //
function Drop(x, y) {
    'use strict';
    // Set X and Y Position //
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    // Show Drop //
    this.showpi = function () {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
    };
    // Move Drop //
    this.movepi = function () {
        y = y - 3;
    };
}

// Setup Canvas Size //
function setCanvasWidth() {
    "use strict";
    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

// Paint Over Canvas For Animation Illusion //
function paintover() {
    'use strict';
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(paintover);
}

// Variables //
var dropi = [];
//var drop = new Drop(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight);

// Get New Drops //
function drop() {
    'use strict';
    var newdrops = new Drop(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight);
    return newdrops;
}

// Draw //
function draw() {
    'use strict';
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropi.length; i = i + 1) {
        dropi[i].showpi();
        dropi[i].movepi();
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

// Listen For "SpaceBar" Key Press //
window.addEventListener('keydown', function pressed(x) {
 'use strict';
 var code = x.keyCode;
        //soundfile = new Audio('blop.wav');
 if (code === 32) {
        //soundfile.play();
        dropi.push(new Drop(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight));
        draw();
    }
});

// Run //
setCanvasWidth();
paintover();
```

```css
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <canvas id="make"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Friend helped me out, i made the mistake of calling draw() everytime i pressed space. he put it in a conditional statement so i only had to call it once. Thanks to all...

```js
// Get Random //
function rand(min, max) {
    "use strict";
    return Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);
}

// Setup Canvas //
var canvas = document.querySelector("#make"),
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

// Create Drop //
function Drop(x, y) {
    'use strict';
    // Set X and Y Position //
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    // Show Drop //
    this.showpi = function () {
        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, 10, 10);
    };
    // Move Drop //
    this.movepi = function () {
        y = y - 3;
    };
}

// Setup Canvas Size //
function setCanvasWidth() {
    "use strict";
    ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}

// Paint Over Canvas For Animation Illusion //
function paintover() {
    'use strict';
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    window.requestAnimationFrame(paintover);
}

// Variables //
var dropi = [];
//var drop = new Drop(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight);

// Get New Drops //
function drop() {
    'use strict';
    var newdrops = new Drop(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight);
    return newdrops;
}

// Draw //
function draw() {
    'use strict';
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropi.length; i = i + 1) {
        dropi[i].showpi();
        dropi[i].movepi();
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

// Listen For Key Press //
window.addEventListener('keydown', function pressed(x) {
 'use strict';
 var code = x.keyCode;
        //soundfile = new Audio('blop.wav');
 if (code === 32) {
        //soundfile.play();
        dropi.push(new Drop(window.innerWidth / 2, window.innerHeight));
        if (dropi.length === 1) {
            draw();
        }
    }
});

// Run //
setCanvasWidth();
paintover();
```

```css
canvas {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
    <body>
        <canvas id="make"></canvas>
    </body>
```